# Showing wrong date when using NSIndianCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get date from week day and year . It work and  get correct Output. But when i am changing CalendarIdentifier then it will show wrong output.

Here is my code

when i am setting CalendarIdentifier is  NSGregorianCalendar

```
 NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:2013];
[components setWeek:2];
[components setWeekday:1];

NSDate *resultDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

> ```
> output is :-  2013-01-05 18:30:00 +0000
> ```

When i am changing CalendarIdentifier is NSIndianCalendar

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIndianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:2013];
[components setWeek:2];
[components setWeekday:1];

NSDate *resultDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

> ```
> Output is :- 2091-03-24 18:30:00 +0000
> ```

what am i doing wrong ?.. Thanks in advance..

**EDIT**

According to Midhun MP answer my output is correct.
now my problem is if i am using NSGregorianCalendar
output is :-  2013-01-05 18:30:00 +0000 day of that date is saturday.

According to NSGregorianCalendar saturday is start of week and friday is end of week . 
I want find similar start and end of week i.e Monday and sunday in india or it is different ??? .

Comment: What are you doing wrong?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks for reply .date of year, day and month  is wrong . It show 2091. i want to show date from week number and year . in NSGregorianCalendar it show perfect

Comment: If NSGregorianCalendar gives you a perfect solution, then what's the issue that you are trying to address?

Comment: when i am changing  calendaridentifire is NSIndianCalendar it will show wrong date .

Comment: ...  I would talk to someone who speaks your language if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

The output is correct.

Indian Calendar is 78 Years back of Gregorian Calendar. So 2013 in Indian Calendar is equal to 2091 in Gregorian Calendar.

Also the first month of Indian Calendar is the Third Month of Gregorian Calendar (March)

```
2013 (Indian Calendar)       + 78  = 2091 (Gregorian Calendar)
3 (March in Indian Calendar) + 2   = 5 (May in Gregorian Calendar)
```

Likewise there is change in day also.

Reference : [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_national_calendar)

Comment: thanx for reply. i agree for year . but i get wrong date and day.

Comment: @Kalpesh: I added the explanation for month and day also.

Comment: ok fine ... if i am using Gregorian Calendar it show start sweek day is saturday and end week day is friday . I want start week day is monday and end day is saturday . how can achive this by using Gregorian Calendar

Comment: @Kalpesh: Where you want to change the day ? I didn't understand where you having the issue ?

Comment: @Kalpesh: I don't know this is what you are looking for : `[gregorian setFirstWeekDay:1];`

Comment: @ Midhun MP check my edited question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32864/discussion-between-kalpesh-and-midhun-mp)